# error passing empty credentials to firestore emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

I am trying to seed some sample data into my local firestore emulator database. I adapted the example from [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/59#issuecomment-497217177)

My code looks like this:

```
const {Firestore} = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const {credentials} = require('grpc');

const db = new Firestore({
  projectId: 'my-project-id',
  servicePath: 'localhost',
  port: 8100,
  sslCreds: credentials.createInsecure(),
  customHeaders: {
    "Authorization": "Bearer owner"
  }
});

async function load_data() {
  await db.collection("mycollection").doc("myid").set({ foo: "test" })
}
load_data();
```

But I receive the error

> this.credentials._getCallCredentials is not a function

Tested on node 10 and 12 with same error.

Library versions:

- @google-cloud/firestore 3.5.1
- grpc 1.24.2

Is there a better approach to writing to local emulated firestore? Or is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to use two different implementations of gRPC together. Internally firestore uses `@grpc/grpc-js`, so that is what you should be using. You should only need to change the second line to `const {credentials} = require('@grpc/grpc-js');` and switch the dependency to that library.